# Fractional Letterspacing in Outlook 2010 not working

Tags: css, outlook, html-email, letter-spacing

I'm designing a HTML email right now. So far so good it all worked fine. But my client wished for a tiny bit more `letter-spacing`. `letter-spacing` of 1px is to much, but no `letter-spacing` is to bulky.

I used `letter-spacing` of .5px in some places.

It looks good in all major clients except Outlook. In Outlook the `letter-spacing` rounds to 1px. Is there any method to fix show the right `letter-spacing` in Outlook as well?

```
<td style="font-family: Georgia, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height: 19px; 
letter-spacing: .7px;  color: #000000;">
    Text
</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

Outlook [*does*](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) support `letter-spacing`, but the Outlook 2007-2016 are finicky with it and round pixels to the nearest point (pt). Sounds like you've discovered this already.

**You can try `em`'s, eg `letter-spacing: .7em;`.**

I certainly don't want to tell you how to design, but emails don't need to be pixel perfect in every email client. Outlook can be particularly tough to get exact. If your client persists, it might be a good time to educate them on the ins and outs of email design.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried using eM, but it got rounded aswell. :(

This Client is from the print industry. So for them everything needs to be perfect. Also almost 80% of their audience is using Outlook. 

But Thank you very very much for your attempt!

Comment: Is your client using Outlook? It's one thing if _your client_ cares about letter spacing, it's another thing if _their audience_ cares.

Comment: Haha I wish they wouldn't be! Also I'm a bit of a perfectionist. I wouldn't want to send the Mail without it being perfect and goodlooking in every Client. Now I talked to them and we agreed on no letter-spacing!

Comment: Glad it worked out.
"goodlooking in every client" and usable - absolutely!
"perfect in every client" like, pixel-perfect - Your time is likely better spent elsewhere.
/ rant 